# BeatifulSoup get_text() function including css

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

Using this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
    font-size: 190%/1.2em;
    margin: 1.58em 16% 1.58em 16%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="d0e119">De goede Martha zou bijna gedacht hebben veel te laat te zijn, want het middageten was nauwelijks aan de kook op het fornuis
in de keuken.</p>
<p id="d0e121">&#8220;Goed,&#8221; zeide ik bij mij zelven, &#8220;als hij honger heeft, zal mijn oom, die de ongeduldigste mensch is, luide jammerkreten aanheffen.&#8221;</p>

 <p>Sacr\xe9 bleu!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and running this python script:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import codecs



  with codecs.open('test2.htm', encoding='utf-8') as fileHandle, codecs.open('fname.txt', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as outfile: 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(fileHandle, "lxml")
        print (soup.get_text())
        outfile.write(soup.get_text())
        fileHandle.close()
        outfile.close()
```

I get this output:

```
    body
    {
    font-size: 190%/1.2em;
    margin: 1.58em 16% 1.58em 16%;
    }



De goede Martha zou bijna gedacht hebben veel te laat te zijn, want het middageten was nauwelijks aan de kook op het fornuis
in de keuken.
“Goed,” zeide ik bij mij zelven, “als hij honger heeft, zal mijn oom, die de ongeduldigste mensch is, luide jammerkreten aanheffen.”
Sacr\xe9 bleu!
```

Why is the styling info extracted as if it were text? I thought get_text JUST gets the text (=stuff in the body tags?)

Comment: If you can use lxml `from lxml import html;tree = html.fromstring(_html) ;tree.xpath("//*[not(self::style) and not(self::script)]/text()")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `soup.get_text()` would collect the texts of all of the elements on the page. It does not know that you don't want there to be `style` element's text. A common approach is to *remove elements like `style` and `script` from the tree and then get the text*:

```
tags_to_remove = ['script', 'style']
for tag in soup.find_all(tags_to_remove):
     tag.extract()

print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: would be nice if get_text took a keyword arg for tags to ignore